# Append to a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python

```
self.LOG_DIR_LIST_BACKEND = [AMPLI_LOG, VAR_LOG, CORE_DUMP_LOG]
backend_nodes = [backend-1, backend-2, backend-3]

self.log_in_nodes = []
log_file = {}
for LOG_DIR_BACKEND in self.LOG_DIR_LIST_BACKEND:
    for node_backend in backend_nodes:
        log_in_nodes 'find %s -type f -name \"*log.*.gz\"' % LOG_DIR_BACKEND
        log_file[node_backend] = log_in_nodes
        self.log_in_nodes.append(log_file)
    print "Logs are ", self.log_in_nodes
```

Expected output :

```
[{backend-1: AMPLI_LOG, VAR_LOG, CORE_DUMP_LOG, backend-2: AMPLI_LOG, VAR_LOG, CORE_DUMP_LOG, backend-3: AMPLI_LOG, VAR_LOG, CORE_DUMP_LOG}]
```

When I print self.log_in_nodes, the output is everytime new, it is not appending. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you provided expected and actual outputs, but I'm guessing the issue is that you're just appending the same mutable dictionary to the list every time rather than copies of it?

Comment: Expected is -  [{backend-1: AMPLI_LOG, VAR_LOG, CORE_DUMP_LOG, backend-2: AMPLI_LOG, VAR_LOG, CORE_DUMP_LOG, backend-3: AMPLI_LOG, VAR_LOG, CORE_DUMP_LOG}]

Comment: Actual is printed in 3 parts-  [{backend-1: AMPLI_LOG,backend-2: AMPLI_LOG,backend-3: AMPLI_LOG}]        [{backend-1: VAR_LOG,backend-2: VAR_LOG,backend-3: VAR_LOG}]        [{backend-1: CORE_DUMP_LOG,backend-2: CORE_DUMP_LOG,backend-3: CORE_DUMP_LOG}]

Comment: Is `backend-1` a string (e.g. `"backend-1"` with quotes), or is `backend` a variable that you're subtracting different amounts from? Your outputs are mostly nonsense, since you seem to have omitted quotation marks or brackets or something. There are way too many commas in your dict! Please give a [MCVE], not bogus code.

Comment: Are you looking for a dictionary of lists, rather than a list of dictionaries? Your desired output looks a lot more like that (though as it is, it's bogus syntax. A proper dict with list values would be `{'backend-1': ['AMPLI_LOG', 'VAR_LOG', 'CORE_DUMP_LOG'], 'backend-2': ['AMPLI_LOG', 'VAR_LOG', 'CORE_DUMP_LOG']}`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run this method, it will reset `self.log_in_nodes`, because you are doing:

```
self.log_in_nodes = []
```

If you want to append stuff to that list, either make this like a class variable or put it outside the class, and initialize only once.

Option one:

```
 class Foo
     log_in_nodes = []

 def your_method(self ...):
     log_file = {}
     for LOG_DIR_BACKEND in self.LOG_DIR_LIST_BACKEND:
         for node_backend in backend_nodes:
             ....
             self.log_in_nodes.append(log_file)
```

Option 2: 
     LOG_IN_NODES = []

```
 class Foo

 def your_method(self ...):
     log_file = {}
     for LOG_DIR_BACKEND in self.LOG_DIR_LIST_BACKEND:
         for node_backend in backend_nodes:
             ....
             LOG_IN_NODES.append(log_file)
```

In both cases the list is initialized once, and appended every time you call the method.

#### side notes:

What is this:

```
log_in_nodes 'find %s -type f -name \"*log.*.gz\"' % LOG_DIR_BACKEND`
^^^^^^^^^^^^  Did you miss type this?   forget an assignment?
```

probably you meant:

```
log_in_nodes = 'find %s -type f -name \"*log.*.gz\"' % LOG_DIR_BACKEND
```

Instead of:

```
backend_nodes = [backend-1, backend-2, backend-3]
```

You can do:

```
backend_nodes = range(backend - 1, backend - 4, -1)
```

although not really shorter, it is immediately clear what it is doing, compared to the way you wrote the code.